# Windows Workgroup Application Installation Restrictions

Tags: windows, user-accounts

I want to restrict the Windows Workgroup user to install the applications and i want to allow the user to install the specific applications. User will be having Local Admin privilage. Any solution?

Comment: Remove local admin privileges from user.

Comment: Actually the thing is, I want the user to install specified/Particular applications of our organization's only.  Rest it should deny.

Comment: Any Suggestions....

Comment: Why won't you install them yourself, possibly using a group policy for that?

Answer (score 0):

What it really seems like you want is a user self service tool to install applications rather than the user installing applications. Unfortunately, most tools like software center are not free. You could try using Chocolatey Gui. If setting this up would take too long and the application is used everywhere with no licensing limitations then you could just deploy it everywhere and make it part of the image. Alternatively, you can silently install it as needed/requested in the background using your workstation administrator privileges remotely, assuming the install file is available on a system within the workgroup in a share.

Comment: flagged for product placement. Windows workgroup has no ability for this native. obly Active directory can do this. if a workgroup is really in place then only a third party tool can solve this. as moreover it's not common practices to run an corporation environment as a work environment and makes me suspicious that this is a hidden home and enduser question which is off topic.

Comment: I'm not endorsed by this product. And I answered the question.

Comment: product recommendations are off topic.